# bulma scss variable customization in Angular

Tags: angular, npm, bulma

In my Angular application, I want to use bulma css framework so as per documentation guides, I followed steps for installing bulma and bulma saas.
after some steps, I have to add following lines in node scripts in package.json.

```
"scripts": {
  "css-build": "node-sass --omit-source-map-url sass/mystyles.scss css/mystyles.css",
  "css-watch": "npm run css-build -- --watch",
  "start": "npm run css-watch"
}
```

So I have added it to my angular project's package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "css-build": "node-sass --omit-source-map-url ../src/styles.scss ../src/styles.css",
    "css-watch": "npm run css-build -- --watch",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve && npm run css-watch",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
```

now when I am changing my scss file and save it, nothing happens with my css file neither my browser reloads.My local server only reloads when I changed my angular files.
Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you sure you point to the correct path in your 'css-build' script in the pckage.json? It seems to me your styles.scss should be located at `./src/styles.scss`, this is relative to the package.json.

Comment: Also, are you sure the `ng serve` command will return? I dont think so. You probably need to run `ng serve` and `npm run css-watch` in parallel, so either use `ng serve &; npm run css-watch`  in your package.json (if it works, not tested), either run those command in two distinct terminal.

Comment: I am running commands in two distinct terminal and it is working. But first way you suggested to run `ng serve &; npm run css-watch` is giving syntax error.Also I tried to replace &; with || operator but it is not working.